# Xamarin Android tap gesture event handler can not be triggerred

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm learning Xamarin Android and adding a tab gesture to my application. The below is my MainPage.xaml.cs code:

```
namespace WorkingWithWebview
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();   
            webView.Source = "https://www.google.com/";    
            var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();    
            tapGestureRecognizer.NumberOfTapsRequired = 1;    
            tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => {
                Debug.Print("Tap event!");
            };
            webView.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
        }        
    }
}
```

I'm using a WebView to display page and binding tap gesture to it. The tap gesture code is exactly from MS official documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap
.

The below is my MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WorkingWithWebview"
             x:Class="WorkingWithWebview.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <WebView x:Name="webView" WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

But for some reason, the event handler, `Debug.Print()` function can not be triggered. How   to solve it?

Comment: why would you do this?  The WebView natively responds to gestures (ie, hyperlinks and scrolling, etc) so layering another gesture recognizer on top of it will just interfere with its native behavior.

Comment: @Jason The main goal is to use gesture to navigate to different xaml page.

Comment: @Jason Is there a way to force the WebView responds to my gesture?

Comment: I don't know.  Like I said, layering a custom gesture on top of another control that supports its own gestures creates a complex UX situation.  I'd suggest really spending some time thinking about how this will work with custom gestures and native gestures.

Comment: could it work now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use custom renderer to overwrite the **OnTouch** method to achive the effect:

first in your share code,createa custom WebView `MyWebView.cs` :

```
public class MyWebView:WebView
{
}
```

then create `MyWebViewRenderer.cs` in **.Android**:

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Icu.Util;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.Widget;
using App18;
using App18.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat;
using View = Android.Views.View;
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace App18.Droid
{
  class MyWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyWebView, Android.Webkit.WebView>,View.IOnTouchListener
   {
      private Context _context;
      private float preX;
      private float curX;
      private static int MIN_CLICK_DELAY_TIME = 1000;
      private long lastClickTime = 0;
      public MyWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
       {
        _context = context;
       }

      public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
       {
        if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
         {
            Toast.MakeText(_context, "click", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            preX = e.RawX;

         }

        if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
         {
            curX = e.RawX;
            long currentTime = Calendar.Instance.TimeInMillis;
            if (currentTime - lastClickTime < MIN_CLICK_DELAY_TIME)
            {

                Toast.MakeText(_context, "double click", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
            lastClickTime = currentTime;

            Log.Error("time", currentTime + "-----------" + lastClickTime);
            //the distance you could define your own,here is 200,and just a simple judgment of the x direction
            if ((curX - preX) > 200)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(_context, "swipe right", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }

            if ((curX - preX) < -200)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(_context, "swipe left", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }

         }
        return false;
      }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<MyWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control == null)
        {
            var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_context);
            SetNativeControl(webView);
            webView.LoadUrl("https://www.google.com");
            webView.SetOnTouchListener(this);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

finally use in page.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App18"
         x:Class="App18.Page1">
   <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <local:MyWebView  WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="500" ></local:MyWebView>
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

This is the general code snippet, specific requirements you could modify your own

Comment: Could you show me those using statements in your MyWebViewRenderer.cs file

Comment: the packages in your MyWebViewRenderer.cs

Comment: i will update later，now is not in front of computer ！

Comment: @JeremyParker i hava updated,are these references u want ? App18 is my project name

Answer (score 0):

This approach is a little bit hacky, but you can add Focus event to the WebView and do whatever you need to do in that event.

```
<WebView Focused="WebView_Focused"/>
```

```
private void WebView_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    // Insert Logic Here
}
```

NOTE: This implementation looks like it will only activate the Focus event on the first focus. If, for some reason, you need to be handle multiple taps, try something like -

```
<WebView x:Name="MyWebView" Focused="WebView_Focused" />
```

```
private void WebView_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    // Your Logic Here
    MyWebView.Unfocus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. But, Is it possible to hack a double click and/or swipe gesture?

Comment: If you need double click or swipe gesture, I would look into a CustomRenderer like the answer from Leo Zhu.